# ERROR IN SQL COMMAND / FOREIGN KEY PROBLEM

Tags: mysql, sql

I was training to create a table in SQL, but I got this message

[image]

The ideia of the code is this one:

/* criando as tabelas */

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTES (
    IDCLIENTE INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CLIENTE VARCHAR(10)NOT NULL,
    ESTADO CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    SEXO ENUM ('M','F') NOT NULL,
    STATUS VARCHAR (10)
);

CREATE TABLE VENDEDORES (
    IDVENDEDOR INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NOME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
    );


CREATE TABLE PRODUTOS (
    IDPRODUTO INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRODUTO VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    PRECO FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE VENDAS (

     IDVENDA INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,

    TOTAL INT NOT NULL,


     ID_VENDEDOR INT ,
     FOREIGN KEY (ID_VENDEDOR)
     REFERENCES VENDEDORES(IDVENDEDOR)


        ID_CLIENTE INT,
     FOREIGN KEY (ID_CLIENTE)
     REFERENCES CLIENTES(IDCLIENTE) 

);


CREATE TABLE ITENS_VENDAS(


    ID_VENDA INT NOT NULL,
    ID_PRODUTO INT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY ID_VENDA
    REFERENCES VENDAS(IDVENDA)

    FOREIGN KEY ID_PRODUTO
    REFERENCES PRODUTOS(IDPRODUTO)

    QUANTIDADE INT NOT NULL,

    VALOR_UNITARIO FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL,

    VALOR_TOTAL FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL,

    DESCONTO FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL
);
```

I was creating that from this idea of this flowchart:

[image]

I understand that I'm making a mistake in the foreign key part

but i can't understand what is wrong.

P.S: I'am new at programing in sql.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax error

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE CLIENTES (
>       IDCLIENTE INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
>       CLIENTE VARCHAR(10)NOT NULL,
>       ESTADO CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
>       SEXO ENUM ('M','F') NOT NULL,
>       STATUS VARCHAR (10)
>     );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE VENDEDORES (
>       IDVENDEDOR INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
>       NOME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL
>       );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE PRODUTOS (
>       IDPRODUTO INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
>       PRODUTO VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
>       PRECO FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL
>     );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE VENDAS (
>     
>        IDVENDA INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     
>       TOTAL INT NOT NULL,
>     
>     
>        ID_VENDEDOR INT ,
>        FOREIGN KEY (ID_VENDEDOR)
>        REFERENCES VENDEDORES(IDVENDEDOR),
>     
>     
>           ID_CLIENTE INT,
>        FOREIGN KEY (ID_CLIENTE)
>        REFERENCES CLIENTES(IDCLIENTE) 
>     
>     );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE ITENS_VENDAS(
>     
>     
>       ID_VENDA INT NOT NULL,
>       ID_PRODUTO INT NOT NULL,
>     
>       FOREIGN KEY (ID_VENDA)
>       REFERENCES VENDAS(IDVENDA),
>     
>       FOREIGN KEY (ID_PRODUTO)
>       REFERENCES PRODUTOS(IDPRODUTO),
>     
>       QUANTIDADE INT NOT NULL,
>     
>       VALOR_UNITARIO FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL,
>     
>       VALOR_TOTAL FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL,
>     
>       DESCONTO FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL
>     );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c572364e53bdff3e9c8234269dbe60ad)*